# Drop Shadow outside the canvas when exporting in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am trying to export the canvas of an illustrator file only to svg but when I try to open the file, the drop shadow of the objects in my file are still visible outside the canvas. I am relatively new to Illustrator.[image]

See the shadows present at the top and bottom of the image.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a clipping mask.

Basically, you prepare a rectangle of the area you really need and put the shadow inside.

Here is the explanation from adobe's website: https://helpx.adobe.com/mx/illustrator/how-to/illustrator-creating-basic-clipping-mask.html

Comment: Thank you, that solved it. I tried doing it with the pathfinder tool earlier on and it didn't work. Aren't the two methods equivalent ?

Answer (score 0):

> Group all your shapes together that you want inside the 'canvas' (ctrl/cmnd-G)
> Create a shape that acts as the border of your canvas and place it on top of your grouped shapes.
> Make a clipping mask, selecting both of the above (right click -> make clipping mask).
> add your desired drop shadow to that clipping mask.

Answer (score 0):

When you export as SVG use *File > Export As*, select SVG as the format, and select the "Use Artboards" option.

[image]

Here's an example result. The artboard will crop the drop shadow.

[image]